# Как запускать 32х разрядные приложения (Linux) в 64х битном окружении?

Tags: x86_64, linux, i686

Под 64 разрядной ОС (Ubuntu 10.04 x86_64) нужно запустить 32х разрядное приложение (CAD пакет Medusa Personal). Немного сомневаюсь, как поступать в таких случаях.
При попытке запустить выдает

> `/opt/medusa4_personal_v5_0/medcolraster/m2d/run/draft: error while loading shared libraries: libtiff.so.3: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64`

насколько я понимаю, это из за разрядности. Вообще вопрос более общий. Как вообще запускать приложения в таких случаях (не конкретно Медузу)? Доставлять библиотеки 32х? Откуда доставлять и какие?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Доставлять библиотеки 32х?

Да

> Откуда доставлять и какие?

Из репозитариев. Вот взять skype, например. Это стандартная проприетарная программа в rpm-пакете. Под 32-бита работает отлично, под 64-битной системой не запускается с выдачей сообщения об ошибке. Приходится вручную доставлять библиотеки. На разных системах - разные.  Но списочек может получиться, например, такой: ia32-libs, lib32asound2, libasound2-plugins. Как видно из названий библиотеки 32-битные. Проблема с проприетарностью лишь та, что просто не все зависимости прописаны.

По медузе решение тоже есть. Необходимо в файле /medusa4/master_project/login добавить строчки с указанием путей к 32-битным библиотекам

```
## added to access 32bit libraries
setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH \
`edpath -a  LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/lib32`
```

Затем сделать ссылку на 32-битную версию библиотеки

```
cd /usr/lib32
sudo ln -s  /usr/lib32/libbz2.so.1.0.4  libbz2.so.1
```

Comment: Вот как. Спасибо. Буду пробовать. А как быть с библиотекой libtiff.so.3? У себя я ее не нашел. Ругается на нее. В репозитории libtiff.so.4 да и та наверное же x86_64.

Comment: @gecube натолкнул на решение. Спасибо огромное.
Сделал так (как нашлось на форуме Медузы)
+ install the 32bit libs with getlibs: sudo getlibs -l libtiff.so.4
+ change in the 32bit folder: cd /usr/lib32/
+ link the library: sudo ln -s libtiff.so.4 libtiff.so.3

Answer (score 0):

Еще можно попробовать 
    linux32 app_name